# How to clone a selected column dynamically in the jquery DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to clone a selected column dynamically in the jquery DataTable?

I need to clone a column(specified by the index) and it should come next the original column. Then need to update the specified column data. While searching about this, I found only row adding and functionalities on row, not on column.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with **`column-selector`** property of DataTable which provide a detail working methods and event support specific to Column only.
The column selector can be given in a number of different forms, to make it easy to apply to your data and use case.

[For More Detail Check Here](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector)